# LabelStyle.... Why won't this code produce red font on half size labels?

Tags: kml

I'm doing a proof-of-concept map.  Goal is half sized labels, with red font, and no icon.   I've tried everything, even copy pasting from the google KML reference manuals and many examples posted here.  What am I missing?   I'm trying to display the map in both Google's "My maps" and also as a called data file at the browser utility gmap4.  The test map should show four labels with Google streetmap of Pennsylvania for a baselayer...... Thanks for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>

<Style id="NoIconRedTextHalfSize">
  <IconStyle>
   <scale>.1</scale>
   <Icon>
      <href>https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-stars.png</href>
   </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
    
    <LabelStyle>
         <Color>FF1400FF</Color>
         <Scale>.5</Scale>
    </LabelStyle>
</Style>

<Folder>
<Placemark>
    <name>Hs-4-C.Sonney</name>
   <styleUrl>#NoIconRedTextHalfSize</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>1,1,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
    <name>Hs-5-B.Jozwiak</name>
   <styleUrl>#NoIconRedTextHalfSize</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>1,1,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
    <name>Hs-6-B.Roae</name>
   <styleUrl>#NoIconRedTextHalfSize</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>1,1,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
    <name>Hs-7-M.Longietti</name>
   <styleUrl>#NoIconRedTextHalfSize</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>1,1,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
    
    
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

The KML syntax includes a number of tags that are not supported by plain Google maps (my map) or by sotfware based on the Google map API.  One of the non-supported tags is .
See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements

To make a label with no icon try making a transparent icon.